# Does android content provider methods need to be synchronized?

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-contentprovider, android-contentresolver

I am using `SQLiteDatabase` as a backend data source for my `Content Providers`, does it require to make `insert`, `update`,`delete`,`applyBatch` methods to be `synchronized` ?, Since I am using singleton object of `SQLiteDatabase` object throughout my application.

> is android `SQLiteDatabase` operations are thread safe ?

If it thread safe i don't need to make the above methods synchronized .After read through this [blog](https://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/10/sqlite-contentprovider-thread-safety.html)

which clearly explains about this issue. But i need to know all the  `SQLiteDatabase` operations are thread safe ?